# I want to addEventListener on php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I want to addEventListener on variable $html_tab when is clicked go to www.google.com

```
    $html_tab .= '<td align="center" valign="middle">'. $row['numeUnitate'] . '</td>';
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
                window.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    var location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
                });
            </script>";
```

Comment: I don't think the window has a `click` event. Try `focus`, that might do what you want.

Comment: @Doge Yes window has `click` event

Comment: You really want the whole window to take the user to google.com on a click?

Comment: What is your aim? The other thing is, you can't add any event to a php variable. In this case PHP is just echoing a string and the browser adds the event to the DOM-Element.
Please specify your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after I've seen an error, I understand your question.

```
var location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Don't use the keywort var in here.
Then it will work.
Otherwise the browser thinks, that you want to declare a new variable!

So, just write only

```
location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

In your example, it should probably be like:

```
   <td id="the_id" align="center" valign="middle"> .....

  <script language='javascript'>
   var elem = document.getElementById('the_id');
   elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
            });
  </script>";
```